# KeyError When Assigning Dictionary Keys and Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, keyerror

I've recently begun learning Python and I wanted to write a script to extract the day of the month from a CSV column (formatted as YYYY/DD/MM) then compare website users to days of the month (and eventually weeks of the month) as a challenge/learning exercise. The gist is that it extracts the CSV info, formats it/converts to integers, and smushes it back together as a dictionary comparing  days 1-31 with the number of site visitors.

My code is below. The error I'm receiving is 'KeyError: 1'on line 29 `result[days] = users`. I think I understand what is happening (kind of - I'm guessing it's not happy with the way I'm trying to assign values to an empty dictionary? It seems to be looking for the integer 1 as a key but not finding it?) but I can't figure out what to do next. I'm about 2 weeks into learning Python so I hope this isn't too stupid a question. What am I doing wrong? How can I make the columns at index [0] and [1] of users_by_day the key and value in my dictionary?

Note: I am learning and using Python 3.

```
 import csv
 result = {}
 with open('analytics.csv') as csv_file:
     csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
     line_count = 0
     users_by_day = list(csv_reader)
     for row in users_by_day: #iterate through data

          day = row[0].split('/') #split date to extract day of month

         try: #skip unsplit cells

             day = day[1]
         except Exception as e:
             pass
         row[0] = day #set list column to extracted day value

 users_by_day = users_by_day[1:-1] #strip headers

 for row in users_by_day:
     days = None
     users = None

         days = int(row[0]) #set values to int for math
         users = int(row[1])

     if days is not None:
         if days in result: #trying to check for days in result
             result[days] = users #where key error occurs
         else:
             result[days] += users

 print(result)
```

Comment: The line `result[days] = users` wouldn't generate this error but `result[days] += users` would. First ensure which line is affected and better place a comment to this line instead of line numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [setdefault()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault) call on dictionaries is great for this kind of thing, and is preferable to the `if {thing} in {dict}` construct.

So the following code:

```
if days in result:  # trying to check for days in result
    result[days] = users  # where key error occurs
else:
    result[days] += users
```

Could become:

```
result.setdefault(days, 0)
result[days] += users
```

Comment: This works great. Simple and elegant. I will research the function so I understand what it's doing better. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

in the `else` part , if days not in result, the equation certainly would generate an error, because it using an key that dosent exit:

```
result[days] =result[days]+ users
```

but do you really mean like :

```
 if days is not None:
     if days not in result:     #if result doesn't have that day
         result[days] = users   #get the day and its value into result
     else:                      #if result already has the day value
         result[days] += users  #summary the value
```

Answer (score 0):

Options aside from `dicty.setdefault(key, val)` and `if key in dicty`, include:

## Try / Except

```
try:
    dicty[key] += value
except KeyError:
    dicty[key] = value
```

## collections.defaultdict()

Using [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
dicty = defaultdict(int)
dicty[key] += value
```

Last line will execute to the effect of `dicty[key] = value` or `dicty[key] += value` as appropriate (really what it does is, if the key is not found, run `dicty[key] = int()` before running `dicty[key] += value` ... you'd have to be careful using this for `*=` therefore).